# Send a code to Varification Code by sms to user using my iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am working on a application in which I have verify a users number.I will get the user's permission to send message from MFMessageComposeViewController.But I want to hide the code that I am sending in the message body from the user.I read that I can't send message from the
iPhone without showing MFMessageComposeViewController. And Apple will reject my application if i will use any third party framework for that.So what can i do to get my work done.Can any one guid me with that.Any help is welcome.Thanks in advance 
Thanks
Happy Coding

Comment: You want to send a SMS message but hide its contents from the phone's owner? That seems... unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative method of sending an SMS on a non jailbroken phone.

Is the SMS method of sending critical? Otherwise - I would consider a behind the scenes webservice using HTTPS.

Comment: i don't understand.Can you please give me some example.

Comment: for example open a web service on a server that accepts a PUT HTTPS request in the following way: https://www.yourverificationserver.com/verify_user?verificationcode=1234